# Mock in multithreading context for testing in Python

Tags: python, django, multithreading, unit-testing

In a Django project, I would like to write a test for a function that is used in a multiprocessing context (Processing.create_all_files). If I were using a single thread, I would do 'mock' in order to check the parameters used for calling a given function (FileCreator.create in my case).

However, once the function FileCreator.create is called by a multiprocessing.Pool, mock does not work anymore with it.

How should I do my test for create_all_files? Thanks.

`test_program.py`:

```
def test_create_all_files(self):
    file_paths = [ (...) ] # Initialize file_paths
    processing = Processing()
        with mock.patch('FileCreator.create', return_value=True) as create:
            with mock.patch('os.path.isfile', return_value=False):
                processing.create_all_files()
                calls = create.call_args_list

        for file_path in file_paths:
            self.assertTrue(((file_path),) in calls)


program.py

def unwrap_self_create_one_file(arg):
    return Processing.process_one_file(*arg)

class Processing:
    (...)

    def create_one_file(self, file_path):
       if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        FileCreator.create(file_path) # CREATE FILE

        def create_all_files(file_paths):
       (...) # define args_lst considering file_paths
       ncpus = 4
           pool = multiprocessing.Pool(ncpus)
           pool.map(unwrap_create_one_file, args_lst, chunksize=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue have nothing to do with multithreading but it is more related on 
[Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch).

In your test you use `FileCreator.create(file_path)` to create your file object so I guess you have something like `from mymodule import FileCreator` in `program.py`.

What you should do in these case is `patch` the `FileCreator` reference in `program` by:

```
with mock.patch('program.FileCreator.create', return_value=True) as create:
```

Comment: Ok! Thanks. I misunderstood the point related to 'Where to patch'... now I wonder why it worked before adding multithreading support.

Answer (score 4):

After adding multithreading you risk your 'patch' to go out of scope, in other words, when executing `FileCreator.create` on a different thread chances are the `with patch()` statement has ended.

Comment: Even when using the @patch.object annotation on a test method, the thread could run when the test method has ended so it is necessary to join threads inside the test method.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a little library that handles thread safe magic mocking.

It can be problematic to refactor a massive test suite, so this library allows you to patch the base class call to mocking `__getattr__` with an RLock.

https://github.com/AtakamaLLC/tsmock

`pip install tsmock`

You can do this:

```
from tsmock import MagicMock
```

Or this:

```
from tsmock import thread_safe_mocks
thread_safe_mocks()
```

Either one gets you the correct call count.